# spring boot, jetty, liquibase, jar, not find implementation of liquibase.logging.Logger

Tags: java, jar, spring-boot, liquibase

`Boot 1.1.3.RELEASE` app with `gradle 2.0` and when I fire `./gradlew bootRun` everything works fine but when I fire the app with

`java -jar -Dspring.profile.active=prod build/lib/myapp.jar`.

I see always an error:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not find implementation of liquibase.logging.Logger
    at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.newInstance(ServiceLocator.java:192)
    at liquibase.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:44)
    ... 38 more
```

What's wrong? I was searching this issue in spring boot docs and here on stackoverflow and didn't find anything helpful

**SOLUTION for now, in future releases should be fixed**

downgrade liquidbase from 3.2.0 to 3.1.1

Comment: How did you create `myapp.jar`? What gradle task did you use?

Comment: there is gradle auto task from springboot plugin but you can call it directly ./gradlew bootRepackage

Comment: Have you tried `gradle build`?

Comment: I don't know why but downgrading liquibase from 3.2.0 to 3.1.1 helped to resolve this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug in 3.2.0 that caused this problem has been fixed in 3.2.3 and above.

Comment: strange, because I thought I've tested my app with 3.2.2 and still got that error... maybe I didn't do `gradle clean` will check that out

Comment: Yes, i'm facing the same problem with the 3.2.2 version. I've tried with 3.2.1 version and there is still this bug.

Comment: I confirm, there is still this bug in 3.2.2

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it for 3.2.3 or 3.3.0.

Comment: I have a fix in for the upcoming 3.2.3 release.

Comment: 3.2.3 worked for me, can I suggest editing the answer?

Comment: I updated the answer to 3.2.3. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: I found this while trying to resolve `liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException`, and found that I get the issue with Liquibase 3.10.3 when the repackage task is run with `executable=true`.  This seems to be a classloader error specific to whatever Spring Boot is doing to allow `./myapp.jar` to be run (i.e. like a shell script) under Linux.